# PHP ec2 version package

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

When i try to install PHP witch cookbook i use his commande:

```
yum -d0 -e0 -y install php71
```

when i run the instance i got this error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
yum -d0 -e0 -y install php71-7.1.15-1.31.amzn1
```

but when i run th commande manually, it's worked but he install this version:

```
[root@saml2-test3 ec2-user]# yum -d0 -e0 -y install php71
[root@saml2-test3 ec2-user]# php -v
PHP 7.1.25 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2019 22:10:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

I don't know why in the log file he try to install this version php71-7.1.15 and in the terminal he installed this version PHP 7.1.25
Can you explain to me why i got this and how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

not sure whether you are using the [`package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html) resource (or its subclasses, such as [`yum_package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_yum_package.html)). you can utilize the `yum_package` resource to install `php71`

```
yum_package 'php71' do
  options '-d0 -e0'
end
```

maybe you can ditch the `options` part if you did not use `yum_package` in your original issue.